Postioning the component next to the active cursor position using Tailwind CSS
File: PostInput.jsx
import {useState, useEffect} from "react"
import MentionSelect from "./MentionSelect";
export default function PostInput() {
const [message, setMessage] = useState("")
const [isAtSymbol, setIsAtSymbol] = useState(false)
const [taggedUser, setTaggedUser]=useState(null);
const [cursorPosition, setCursorPosition] = useState({start:0, end:0});
const updateCursorPosition = (event) => {
setCursorPosition({top:event.target.selectionStart,end:event.target.selectionEnd});
};

useEffect(()=>{
if(message.includes('@')){
  setIsAtSymbol(true);
}
else{
  setIsAtSymbol(false);
}
},[message])


console.log(message);
console.log(cursorPosition);


return (
<div className=' p-3 flex flex-col items-center justify-center gap-7 h-auto'>
  <div className="relative">
  <textarea rows={4} cols={60} placeholder="Create a post ..." className="resize-none rounded-md text-gray-600 outline-none p-3 " value={message} onChange={(e)=> setMessage(e.target.value)} onKeyUp={updateCursorPosition}></textarea>
  {isAtSymbol && <MentionSelect taggedUser ={taggedUser} setTaggedUser={setTaggedUser} setIsAtSymbol={setIsAtSymbol} cursorPosition={cursorPosition}/>}
</div>
<div className="relative left-60">
<button className="bg-customPink px-10 py-2 rounded-md text-black font-bold absolute right-0">Post</button></div>
</div>
 )}

File: MentionInput.jsx
  import {useState} from "react";

  const users = ['Tommy','Steve','Danny','Alex','Jones','Charlie','Alexis','Cherie','Reagan','Lacy','Angela','Codi','Gia','Gianna','Luna','Dee'];


   export default function MentionSelect({taggedUser, setTaggedUser, setIsAtSymbol, cursorPosition}) {
   const [filteredUsers, setFilteredUsers] = useState([]);


    const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    // Getting the Input Value
    const inputValue = e.target.value;

    if(inputValue !== ''){

    const result = users.filter((user) =>
        user.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase()));
    setFilteredUsers([...result]);
}else{
    setFilteredUsers([]);
}

}

function HandleTag(e){
setTaggedUser(e.target.value);
setIsAtSymbol(false);
}

 console.log(filteredUsers);
 console.log(taggedUser);

 return (
 <div className="w-auto h-auto max-h-48 border-solid border-2 border-black absolute top- 
 3 z-20 p-2 bg-white overflow-y-auto overflow-x-hidden" style={{ left: `${cursorPosition.end*3}px` }}>
 <input type="text" className="rounded-md p-1" onChange={handleInputChange} />
 { filteredUsers.length > 0 && <div className="mt-2 z-20">

{filteredUsers.map((user)=>(
    <div className="flex justify-center items-center gap-7 p-2 text-black hover:bg-slate-600 hover:text-white" key={user}>
    <span className='bg-red-600  rounded-full w-9 h-9 text-center font-semibold p-1'>{user.at(0)}</span>
    <option className='font-semibold hover:cursor-pointer mt-1' value={user} onClick={HandleTag}>{user}</option>
    </div>
))}
</div>}
</div> )}

I am trying to display the MentionInput component over the PostInput component and mainly it should appear just next to the active cursor position and also at the right line (First Line, Second Line).
But here I am not able to achieve it.
After the tagged user is selected, it should display in violet colour inside the textarea element.
What's the issue in the code?
My Goal is to acheive this:



event.target.selectionStart is the index of the caret, not the pixel coordinate. You can't directly use this value to position the MentionInput div.

Also, we want to focus on one topic in one post so I would suggest you remove After the tagged user is selected, it should display in violet colour inside the textarea element as it only add noise to the main problem here.

It is hard to get the caret pixel position in textArea, but if you can replace it into a contenteditable div, it can easily be achieved by replacing @ into a span node and read the position of the node.

Does this answer your question? Get the offset position of the caret in a textarea in pixels As you can see, most solution involves creating a hidden clone of the textArea copying the text before the caret.
